# Webservice works when debugging but not when deployed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, asmx, application-pool

I am pretty new at web services and I am trying to make quite simple one that interacts with a third party software to access SQL server. I am using sqlserver 2012 and visual studio 2012 on windows 8 
This webservice is installed locally in the IIS in the defaultapppool

Now, for testing it I am using a local client installed in my computer and the issue I am having is that if I use `http://localhost/WebService1/Service.asmx` as my web reference my application gets stuck at invoking the webmethod, it just stays there until a timeout exception is thrown and no matter how much time I give it(have tested up to 30 mins) it never gets past this point.

However if I run my web service in another instance of visual studio (which makes it run on this `http://localhost:2533/WebSite1/`) and change the web reference to that address the application works perfectly and I can access all my webmethods without any problem.

This is a project for a client that only wants the webservice, not the client application but I am worried that if I deploy my webservice in his server he will have the same issues I am having.

I just don't know if it's the client, the webservice, the permissions or the applications pool fault. I can't figure it out and I've been testing all kind of solutions for days now.

So yeah, I can't figure out what's the issue, how come the webservice works perfectly on the development environment but not once I install it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I see, I did not know that, so maybe the issue is from compatibility between new technologies and me using asmx?

Comment: I doubt it's a compatibility issue - I just thought you should know that you're using the wrong tool. ASMX is ancient and almost unsupported.